# how to set an input element to have the same width of its span container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

It seems to be a trivial question, but I'm not succeeding in doing it:

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="well span12 form-inline muse-src-evt-bar">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" style="width: 100%"/>              
            </div>
            <div class="span8">
                test
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can notice the `input` element has a `style="width: 100%"` attribute, but it seems to set a width that goes over the `span4` container width.

[image]

So:

1. I wonder why it behaves like this so as not to repeat this error again
2. How could I solve this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you have set `style="width:100%"` it exhibits property of `span12` and overrides `span4`.I think this might be the reason behind that. You can try by removing style, it will set `input` in `span4`

Comment: I think it simply "overspans" by setting its right border to match with the right border of the `space` element that keeps two `div span` saparated.